# How to check if certain value exist in csv file with PHP

Tags: php, database, laravel, csv

I've a field in my database which has csv values, if I get the value in a variable it looks like

> `$data = "dell, dell7, jhon5, doe4";`
>    
>   //these are user id's

I need to check if a certain id is already in this variable.
I used `explode()` with `foreach()` and it worked well. But, I need to do this in several times and my code become messy.

Is there any other way?

I'm using Laravel(Lumen)

Comment: `I need to do this in several times and my code become messy` mind elaborating as this is not clear why is that so.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  I need to explode and foreach for several times, for different queries in my database. As, I'm creating an API, I want to reduce the server pressure and not interested in running nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkId($id){
    $data = "dell, dell7, jhon5, doe4";
    $array = explode(",", $data);
    return in_array($id, $array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative will be **preg_match()**, like this -

```
$data = "dell, dell7, jhon5, doe4";
$search = 'dell';
if(preg_match("/\b".$search."\b/i", $data)){
echo 'found';
}
```

I am not sure about this solution. But this strikes in my mind when I saw your question.